# SP 2013: Content type forms not appearing – only default

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, custom-form

Using OOTB and SPD.

I have a workflow that assigns tasks. The tasks use a specific content type which has different task outcome choices. This part works fine.
Within content types I would like to use a custom form.

- In SPD, from the task list, I create a new ‘edit form’, associate it
  with the specific task list above, and basically make some fields in
  the aspx page read by replacing ‘edit’ with ‘display’. I add some
  helper text for usage clarity. Etc..
- I place the path to the new form in the content type, ‘edit form’
  location: /Lists/Tasks/CustomForm.aspx
- This is ignored when the task is created. The default task ‘edit
  form’ is used. --> Why?

Kind regards,
- max

Not sure what is going on. I wait 24 hours and everything works. Servers need to sync up or something??